# Redirect Blogger custom domain posts to another domain

Tags: wordpress, redirect, blogger

I have a blogger blog on `http://blog.example.com` and I've moved the blog to a new site using WordPress and set up redirects inside WordPress to redirect blogger posts URLs to new URLs for example:
the post on blogger is: `http://blog.example.com/2016/12/google.html`
the post URL on the new site is: `https://subdomain.domain.com/google/`
I've set redirects inside WordPress to redirect from `https://subdomain.domain.com/2016/12/google.html` TO `https://subdomain.domain.com/google/`

So all what I want is a code to add in the old blogger blog to redirect each page to another page in the new domain, for example:

Redirects from: `http://blog.example.com/2016/12/google.html` TO `https://subdomain.domain.com/2016/12/google.html`

and `http://blog.example.com/2015/11/yahoo.html` TO `https://subdomain.domain.com/2015/11/yahoo.html`

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Locate the  tag in the header section and insert the following code after the  tag: http://www.yoursite.com/'" /> Replace "http://www.yoursite.com" with the URL of the website to which you want to redirect your blog.

[Original article](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/make-blogspot-redirect-another-69368.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not what I'm looking for the code redirects all pages to the new website homepage, I want a code to redirect every URL to another URL with the domain of the new website instead of the old (every post to the same post but on the other website)

Answer (score 0):

Switch from compose to HTML in your post edit and put this code inside the post body.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = 'http://your-external-link';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's the first time I publish a JavaScript but I'm open to suggestion,edit,comments ...

The idea is to put the following script in blogger template so it'll redirect automatically the user.

**Do not forget to change the variables `googleBaseURL` and `wordpressBaseURL`.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    var googleBaseURL = 'http://blog.example.com/', // We define what's our blogger URL
    wordpressBaseURL = 'https://subdomain.domain.com/', // We define what's our wordpress URL
    requestedURL = window.location.href, // We get the URL requested by the user
    requestedPage = requestedURL.split(googleBase)[1], // We get the requested page
    newURL = wordpressBase + requestedPage; // We create our new URL

    window.location = newURL; // We redirect
</script>
```

Here's a snippets which resume your explanation.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('message'),
     googleBaseURL = 'http://blog.example.com/', // We define what's our blogger URL
     wordpressBaseURL = 'https://subdomain.domain.com/', // We define what's our wordpress URL
     requested = 'http://blog.example.com/2016/12/google.html', // URL requested by user
     requestedPage = requested.split(googleBaseURL)[1]; // Requested page by user

 div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "From: " + requested + "<br />"; // Requested url
 div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "The script redirect the user to:  " + wordpressBaseURL + requestedPage; // Redirect to this url
```

```html
<div id=message></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert the code shown below just after the “” tag in the blogger template after replacing the generalized content to your own in the code below.

```
<b:if cond="’data:blog.url" =="“http://your-blog-name.blogspot.com/YEAR/MONTH/BLOG-POST-SLUG.html”‘"><meta content="’0;url=http://yoursite.com/NEW-BLOG-POST-SLUG.html’" http-equiv="’refresh’/"></b:if>
```

[Source](https://upfoss.com/how-to-301-permanent-redirect-blogger-blogspot-blog-to-domain/)